# how to do 2 continuous redirect in django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

in my view I'm doing some calculation and then based on that result I'll show a new page where I can show success message and then automatically in 3 seconds it will redirect to another url.

```
def home(request):
   #do some calculation
   return HttpResponse('success') # and after 3 seconds it will redirect to new page.
   # here I  dont know how to proceed further
```

OR

```
def home(request):
   #do some calculation
   return render(request, template) # and after 3 seconds it will redirect to new page.
   # here I  dont know how to proceed further
```

Comment: Why have you just changed my accepted answer? Is it worse than the other one? I think I explained you much more than the other guy

Comment: J. C. Rocamonde your answer was better I agree with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot accomplish this in Django. Once the page has loaded, you'll need to use JavaScript to redirect the user. So in your template, you would need something like this:

```
<script>
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = "redirect_url";
  }, 3000);
</script>
```

Comment: BTW, type="text/javascript" is not required in HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

This has to be with HTML. If you say "after 3 seconds", just write the following code in your template and it'll redirect you to wherever you want:

```
<script>
// redirect to google after 3 seconds
window.setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}, 3000);
</script>
```

By the way, I have noticed you do not really get the usage of Django rendering here. If you return plain text with `HttpResponse` you can't do anything from client side. Rendering a template is the only way unless you code it all in the HttpResponse part which I do not really recommend.

You cannot redirect a user from the server side. You can just return a certain hypertext fragment which will make the browser understand it's got to redirect, which is what I have just written up there.